# I have few controller options in XCode Interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

Sorry for newbie question but I am new to XCode, I am using XCode 4.4.1.

Could you tell me please how can I get more of the controllers to drag (see the image below) to Interface builder story board (for example Collection View Controller).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using iOS SDK 5 you don't have access to Collection View Controller which is available from iOS SDK 6, you need to have Xcode 4.5 developer preview.

Comment: :( , Is there any way to add custom controllers and controlls to Interface builder templates? Or download libraries to xcode with other controllers?

Comment: No, XCode 4 can only add custom controllers programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest xCode from:
https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

then you can use the "Collection View Controller".